# How to place a ForeignKey constraint on a JSON column with sqlalchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm building an application where the user can add arbitrary fields to a piece of equipment.

These fields are modeled as a `Field` <s>object</s> table in the database.  The Equipment table has a JSONB "data" column, where the key is the field name and the value is the property value.  However, this currently isn't enforced by the database.  I can't use a traditional extra link table (whatever they're actually called) because the property needs to have an actual value associated with it.

To clarify, the constraint that I want to enforce is that all of the keys to `data` must exist in `field.name`.

Field table:

```
| name (PrimaryKey) | type (enum) | extra (JSONB)                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| ram               | 'float'     | {"unit": "GB"}                |
| cpus              | 'integer'   | NULL                          |
| model             | 'enum'      | {"values": ["DL385", "R710"]} |
```

Equipment table:

```
|                   id                 | ... |                  data (JSONB)             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1e2bda05-2457-48df-8a8b-4e54a0176c57 | ... | {"ram": 100, "model": "DL385"}            |
| b65e2547-a4b5-4121-bed3-10f1a026f88a | ... | {"ram": 512, "cpus": 2, "model": "R710"}  |
```

Python code:

```py
class Equipment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'equipment'

    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()))
    parent_rack = Column(UUID, ForeignKey('rack.id'), nullable=False)
    data = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)

    @validates('data')
    def validate_data(self, _, data):
        s = Session().session
        for key in data:
            if len(s.query(Field).filter_by(name=key).all()) != 1:
                raise ValueError('extra data must be a registered field')
        return data


class Field(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'field'

    name = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    type = Column(Enum(FieldType), nullable=False)
    extra = Column(JSONB)

    @validates('extra')
    def validate_extra(self, _, extra):
        self.type.validate_extra(extra)
        return extra
```

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: Would it be possible if I were to use an HSTORE instead?  Is there some other way to accomplish the same thing?